# SQL: Finding the Average per month

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have 2 columns. DATE and DFF (it is a FLOAT for a interest rate. I need to get the average interest rate for every month.
EXAMPLE:
DATE          DFF
2003-01-04   2.0
2003-01-18   2.25
2003-01-25   2.5
2003-02-08   3.0
2003-02-15   3.25
2003-02-27   2.75
2004-05-07   4.0
2004-05-25   4.0

Outcome I am looking for is...
EXAMPLE:
date           avg_dff
2003-01          2.25
2003-02          3.0
2004-05          4.0

Comment: Hi - so what have you tried and what issue are you facing?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query should solve your problem:

```
SELECT
    DATE_FORMAT(DATE, '%Y-%m') AS date,
    AVG(DFF) AS dff
FROM your_table
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(DATE, '%Y-%m')
```